# PYTHON why extend() change my original variable?

Tags: python

I understand that it is something simple but  can't understand it

why is my variable 'a' modified?

```
a=["A","E"]
for x in range(0,2):
    b=a
    b.extend(["I","O","U"])   
    print(b)   
print(a)
```

Output:

```
b(first loop)=['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
b(second loop)=['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'U']
a=['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'U']
```

My variable 'a' would have to be ["A","E"] at the end of the loop and each repetition 'b' would have to be ["A","E","I,"O","U"]

Comment: lists are mutable objects in python

Comment: @Naveen While true, this is not actually at play here. This is more about assignment by reference rather than assignment by instantiation.

Comment: @AdamSmith got it Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both variables `a` and `b` reference the same object.

```
a = ["A","E"]
b = a

print(id(a))
print(id(b))
print(a is b)
```

output:

```
140387638915552
140387638915552
True
```

Comment: what would be the solution in this case?

Comment: The solution would be to copy the object with:```b = a.copy()```. If the object is nested with other objects then ```from copy import deepcopy()``` and ```b = deepcopy(a)```

Comment: for lists it's idiomatic to simply slice without bounds. `b = a[:]` (but this will not deep copy)

Comment: You can also do ```b = [*a]```

Comment: @sarartur also, `deepcopy` is a bit heavy-handed, I'll often just write `[sub.copy() for sub in nested_list]`

Comment: @sarartur true, though only in Python 3.5+